# Contribution of quadrupole term using Quadrupole moment

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, potential, tensor-calculus, multipole-expansion

I read this derivation in  Griffiths that if we obtain dipole moment vector $\vec{p}$ , then dipole term in the potential (due to general distribution far away at $\vec{r}$ ) can be written as $$\frac{\vec{p}.\hat{r}}{4\pi\epsilon_or^2}$$
I was wondering if quadrupole contribution can be written like this in terms of the quadrupole moment matrix. I mean of course, it wont be a dot product but maybe some other way. 
 (Couldn't find it on net!)

Comment: You tagged this question with "multipole-expansion"; didn't you google for that? For me at least, the first link is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion#Expansion_in_spherical_harmonics), which explains that not only the monopole, dipole, and quadrupole can be written in this way, but you can keep going to arbitrarily high multipoles.

Answer (score 1):

Hey the potential term you seek is the following (for gravitational potential. The functional form is exactly the same in the electric potential case.):
$$\phi_{quad}(\vec r)=-G\frac{Q_{ij}\hat r_i\hat r_j}{r^3},$$
$$Q_{ij}=\int\frac{3x_ix_j-\delta_{ij}r^2}{2}_{}\rho(\vec r)d^3\vec r.$$
The quantity $\rho(\vec r)d^3\vec r$ is just the element $dm(\vec r)$ of the mass distribution generating the gravitational potential. This should correspond to the electric charge density generating the electric potential, in your case.

Comment: +1 but I just want to point out that I've (almost?) never seen the factor of $1/2$ in the definition of $Q_{ij}$ — it's usually put in the equation before it.  You may argue that this is just a matter of convention, but $Q_{ij}$ is such a common thing that conventions matter.

Comment: Shouldn't $\phi_{quad}(\vec{r})$ have a summation?

Comment: yes, I assume the summation rule between the repeated indices.

Comment: Just to clarify for the OP, this is called the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), and is pretty common once you need to start writing lots of expressions like that.